# jquery: get value of custom attribute

Tags: jquery, custom-attributes, attr

html5 supports the placeholder attribute on `input[type=text]` elements, but I need to handle non-compliant browsers. I know there are a thousand plugins out there for placeholder but I'd like to create the 1001st.

I am able to get a handle on the `input[placeholder]` element but trying to get the value of the placeholder attribute is returning undefined -  `$("input[placeholder]").attr("placeholder")`.

I'm using jquery 1.6.2.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkYCN/1/). I modified the code to work in a browser that is html5 compatible just for testing purposes.

html

```
<input type="text" name="email" size="10" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS">
```

jquery

```
function SupportsInputPlaceholder() {
    var i = document.createElement("input");
    return "placeholder" in i;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!SupportsInputPlaceholder()) {
        //set initial value to placeholder attribute
        $("input[placeholder]").val($("input[placeholder]").attr("placeholder"));

        //create event handlers for focus and blur
        $("input[placeholder]").focus(function() {
            if($(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder")) {
                $(this).val("");
            }
        }).blur(function() {
            if($(this).val() == "") {
                $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks for any and all help,
B

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need some form of iteration here, as `val` (except when called with a function) only works on the first element:

```
$("input[placeholder]").val($("input[placeholder]").attr("placeholder"));
```

should be:

```
$("input[placeholder]").each( function () {
    $(this).val( $(this).attr("placeholder") );
});
```

or

```
$("input[placeholder]").val(function() {
    return $(this).attr("placeholder");
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$("input[placeholder]").val(function() { return $(this).attr("placeholder"); });` be better?

Comment: Thanks Dennis. when i set a breakpoint on each i found that it's not even entering the function, like it's not finding any elements that match that selector. But when I put a watch on $("input[placeholder]").val() I see "" and if I give the element an initial value I'll see the value.

Comment: @Richard Yeah, that's a bit better.  Probably not too much difference thought.  bflemi3, What browser are you using?  Your code works in Chrome and IE7

Comment: I'm using firefox 5 and I've commented out the if statement that checks if the browser supports the placeholder attribute since firefox 5 supports html5.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.  The code you have provided works fine.  Can you make a jsfiddle/jsbin that shows it?

Comment: here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkYCN/1/).  I commented out the if statement that checks to see if browser is compatible with html5 and changed the placeholder attribute to pholder for testing purposes.

Comment: If you change the framework to jQuery instead of Mootools, it works in FF5, IE7 and Chrome.

Comment: you're right, now I'm even more confused, cause it's not working for on my local vm. Thanks for your help Dennis.

Comment: @Dennis let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2821/discussion-between-bflemi3-and-dennis)

Answer (score 13):

You can also do this by passing function with onclick event

```
<a onclick="getColor(this);" color="red">

<script type="text/javascript">

function getColor(el)
{
     color = $(el).attr('color');
     alert(color);
}

</script>
```

Comment: onlick...hmmm...maybe should be onclick :)