# How to receive a data from a link attributes

Tags: jquery

Can you tell me, how to get data from a link attribute?

Example :

```
<a href="#" target="2">link</a>
```

I want get the data from 'target' attribute to send to server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery: get value of custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7177512/jquery-get-value-of-custom-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

### jQuery

You can also do the same thing in jQuery using the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function.

```js
var target = $("#link").attr("target");

console.log(target);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" target="2" id="link">link</a>
```

### Pure Javascript

You can use [`.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) like below. (I used `document.getElementById()` to get the element, and `.getAttribute` to get the value of the `target` attribute)

```js
var target = document.getElementById("link").getAttribute("target");

console.log(target);
```

```html
<a href="#" target="2" id="link">link</a>
```

Comment: Can you show me the jquery code? I want use jquery code, not a pure JavaScript